# I want to cut polygons in a polygon layer.

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I want to programmatically cut polygons already loaded in arcmap. For instance if originally I have 1 polygon feature and 1 row in attribute table. When I cut them, I should see 2 independent features and 2 rows in attribute table. I tried using the snippet from the [reference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0049000000rs000000) with no luck

Any suggestions how i can get this using C# ArcObjects.
Any suggestions as to how i can achieve this. It

Comment: Can you add some detail regarding how the polygon feature is to be cut? is it an arbitrary cut line? By some intersecting feature/s?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to run the snippet?

Comment: That function returns a GeometryCollection object, you need to break it down into component geometries, update one feature and create a new one or create two features and delete the old one. Can you share what code you have (passing to the reference and returning from).

Comment: If you want to emulate the editor's cut polygons tool, take a look at IFeatureEdit.Split or IFeatureEdit2.SplitWithUpdate.